# Pandas to_csv call is prepending a comma

Tags: python, csv, pandas

I have a data file, apples.csv, that has headers like:

```
"id","str1","str2","str3","num1","num2"
```

I read it into a dataframe with pandas:

```
apples = pd.read_csv('apples.csv',delimiter=",",sep=r"\s+")
```

Then I do some stuff to it, but ignore that (I have it all commented out, and my overall issues still occurs, so said stuff is irrelevant here).

I then save it out:

```
apples.to_csv('bananas.csv',columns=["id","str1","str2","str3","num1","num2"])
```

Now, looking at bananas.csv, its headers are:

```
,id,str1,str2,str3,num1,num2
```

No more quotes (which I don't really care about, as it doesn't impact anything in the file), and then that leading comma. 
The ensuing rows are now with an additional column in there, so it saves out 7 columns. But if I do:

```
print(len(apples.columns))
```

Immediately prior to saving, it shows 6 columns...

I am normally in Java/Perl/R, and less experienced with Python and particularly Pandas, so I am not sure if this is "yeah, it just does that" or what the issue is - but I have spent amusingly long trying to figure this out and cannot find it via searching.

How can I get it to not do that prepending of a comma, and maybe as important - why is it doing it?

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Set `index=False` (the default is `True` hence why you see this output) so that it doesn't save the index values to your csv, see the [docs](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.to_csv.html#pandas.DataFrame.to_csv)

So this:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'a':np.arange(5), 'b':np.arange(5)})
df.to_csv(r'c:\data\t.csv')
```

results in

```
,a,b
0,0,0
1,1,1
2,2,2
3,3,3
4,4,4
```

Whilst this:

```
df.to_csv(r'c:\data\t.csv', index=False)
```

results in this:

```
a,b
0,0
1,1
2,2
3,3
4,4
```

It's for the situation where you may have some index values you want to save

Comment: Wow, instant response and informative - thank you. I had read the docs at that link prior to coming here, but that value and the descriptor there didn't seem to indicate what you described quite well here. Thank you so much for the clarification!

Comment: regarding the quoting, you can pass `quoting=1` to add quotation marks around everything or `quoting=2` for just str values, the default is `csv.QUOTE_MINIMAL` which is the same as `quoting=3`. If my answer fully resolved your question then you can accept it, there will be an empty tick mark at the top left of my answer, thanks

Comment: I haven't had this happen but that might not mean too much. Do you name the columns accordingly in the dataframe? I don't remember specifying the column names when writing usually just do this assuming the cols are already named correctly:                                                  a.to_csv(f, header=True, index=False)

Comment: I tend to create dfs with names or my csv's tend to have a header row. When calling `to_csv` it writes whatever the column names are, even if you didn't name them and your csv did not have any, it will have auto-generated ones from `0.....N` in your df, same with respect to index values, if your csv didn't have any your df will have an auto-generated one