# Pandas does not drop column from dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I trying to drop column with :

```
prediction.drop('1',axis=1)
```

But after saving dataframe to csv with:

```
prediction.to_csv(path_or_buf='./path/file.csv')
```

I open the file and see the following:

```
,TARGET,1
0,1.0,0.0
1,1.0,0.0
2,1.0,0.0
```

Also pandas considers that first column does not exist at all(that one named ' ').
And pandas does this with any dataframe.
If i will attempt to:

```
prediction.drop('',axis=1)
```

It will throw:

```
KeyError: "[''] not found in axis"
```

This is the code that generates data:

```
from keras.models import load_model
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
model = load_model(filepath='./DRISK/model_mlp_a2.h5')
TEST = pd.DataFrame.from_csv('./DRISK/application_test.csv')
expanded = np.zeros((48744,4))
def encode_array(features):
    features = features.fillna(0)
    features = pd.get_dummies(features)
    features = np.array(features)
    features = np.append(features,expanded)
    features = np.reshape(features,(48744,251))
    return features
TEST_X = encode_array(TEST)
prediction = model.predict(x=TEST_X,verbose=1)
prediction = pd.DataFrame(prediction,columns=['TARGET','1'])
prediction.drop('',axis=1)
prediction.to_csv(path_or_buf='./DRISK/predictions.csv')
```

I googled this question extensively, but to no avail.
P.S. Also it ignores first column in every other dataframe.

Comment: Also, use `prediction.to_csv(path_or_buf='./path/file.csv', index=False)` to not have first column in your csv. Those are indexes of the dataframe, not column.

Comment: @EdChum that won't work as it is the index and not the actual column

Comment: @mad_ just realised that there is a dupe for this

Comment: related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30605909/pandas-to-csv-call-is-prepending-a-comma if this resolves your question then I will close as a dupe

Comment: That is index not columns

Comment: @harvpan Thanks,that worked.